# Jboss logger clear MDC during thread lifecycle

Tags: multithreading, mdc, jboss-logging

I need to improve logging in a JavaEE application running on wildfly using jboss logger & logstash, I'm using MDC to store userID but as I'm new with thread usage I'm not figuring out how to clear the MDC before a thread is recycled

I have found different ways to clear the MDC but I think I am missing some pieces of knowledge regarding threads ... :
I've tried to extend Thread :

```
public class MdcThread extends Thread {
    LoggingTools loggingTools = new LoggingTools(MdcThread.class);

    @Override
    public void run() {
        loggingTools.info("MdcThread");
        MDC.clear();
    }
}
```

I've tried to extend ThreadPoolExecutor :

```
public class MdcThreadPoolExecutor extends ThreadPoolExecutor {
    static LoggingTools loggingTools = new LoggingTools(MdcThreadPoolExecutor.class);

...constructors...

    @Override
    public void execute(Runnable command) {
        super.execute(wrap(command));
    }

    public static Runnable wrap(final Runnable runnable) {
        return new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    runnable.run();
                } finally {
                    loggingTools.info("Mdc clear");
                    MDC.clear();
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

But none of these are called ... So I assume ThreadPoolExecutor is a way of using thread but not necessarily used? how can I reach the lifecycle of the threads?

EDIT :
Here is the filter I've used :

```
@WebFilter("/*")
public class MdcFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {

        if (request != null) {
            //add what I want in MDC
        }

        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        MDC.clear();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using logback then WildFly or JBoss Log Manager will not be managing MDC. Most implementations of MDC, and I assume you're using `org.slf4j.MDC` since you're using logback, are thread locals so `MDC.clear()` will only clear the map on that threads MDC map. Have a look at slf4j's [MDC manual](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/mdc.html).

If you want to clear the message diagnostic context you need to do it in the same thread that adds that adds the data you want cleared.

Comment: I'm using import org.jboss.logging.MDC; / as I don't know when an user has finished to use the application I can't clear the map during the life of the thread so I wanted to check before each new thread (or just the recycling one but i don't know if we can be so specific) if the map is not empty then clear it

Comment: `org.jboss.logging.MDC` would work the same. Entries would have to be removed in the same thread as each thread has it's own context.